# Windows UWP StorageFile access is denied exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 10 Mobile app that does logging to a text file. I am using MetroLog foe this. The logging aspect is working great, however, I have a requirement to convert the log file to a byte array so it can be transmitted.

When I try to convert it to byte array,  I get an access is denied exception. I know the issue is with the file because I created a sample text file and I did not have the exception with the sample file and was able to get my byte array.

I am able to get the MetroLog log file from the StorageFolder as a StorageFile successfully, it is just when I try to covert the StorageFile to byte array that I get the exception.

There are only two differences between the test file that worked and the MetroLog log file that gives exception. The MetroLog file has an extension of .log and an attribute of Archive. The test file was a .txt with an attribute of Normal.

I am assuming the issue is because it is am Archive attribute? Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the code I am using to convert the StorageFile to a byte array. I first tried this easier approach:

```
var buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(logFile);
return buffer.ToArray();
```

And then when that didn't work, I also tried calling this method and passing in the StorageFile. With this approach, I got the exception on the using line.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the byte data from a StorageFile
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">The file to read</param>
    public async Task<byte[]> ReadFile(StorageFile file)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = null;
        using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
            using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
            {
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
            }
        }

        return fileBytes;
    }
```

Both of the above worked on the test file but both had exceptions on the log file.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share the code converting StorageFile to the byte array?

Comment: @kurakura88 I have edited the post to show the code you asked for. Didn't think it would help, sorry for not posting but here it is.

Comment: OK. My guess is that your logfile is still opened/ locked by another process, so you can't access it until that other process released it. Not sure how you log the logfile, but I would suggest to flush/ close the log before you are trying to open it.

Comment: @kurakura88 I thought about that, I have two questions to follow that up. First question, I thought that even if the logger has the file open, that I can still open it and read it in a read only mode? The only time this isn't the case is if the logger has an exclusive lock on the file which I don't think it does. Second, I followed the code samples for MetroLog which wraps the logger up into a singleton (lazy initialized) class. The constructor of the singleton configures the log file parameters. I am not sure how to close or release the file, especially given it is a singleton.

Comment: It does really depend on how you implement the log. If you don't lock it exclusively, you should be able to access it, but if it is not flushed, it is going to be an empty log. For your second question, again I am not sure about the sample, but you can just implement a method to flush and close the file. If you don't want to disrupt the current logfile, flush it first, then copy the current logfile to another file and access the copy one afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @kurakura88, this is typically caused by a file having an exclusive lock and that you should flush the file and close it before you try to write.

However, I found the solution specifically for MetroLog. I am using a StreamingFileTarget and there is property that can be set:

```
KeepLogFilesOpenForWrite = false
```

Complete code is:

```
LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal,
            new StreamingFileTarget {RetainDays = RetainDays, KeepLogFilesOpenForWrite = false});
```

After setting this property to false, I no longer get an exception when I try to work with the log file.

Hope this helps.